# Android, Autocomplettextview, force text to be from the entry list

Tags: android, validation, autocompletetextview

Is there a way to force the entry in an autocompletetextview to be one of the elements in the entrylist?

I've found a method called "performValidation" but im not sure what it actually does, and i havent been able to find much documentation or any examples.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `AutoCompleteTextView` has a method called `setValidator()` that takes an instance of the interface `AutoCompleteTextView.Validator` as parameter. `AutoCompleteTextView.Validator` contains `isValid()` with which you can check the value that has been entered, and you can "fix" this string by implementing `fixText()`.

Seems this is the best you can get with `AutoCompleteTextView`, as the documentation for `AutoCompleteTextView.Validator` states the following:

> "Since there is no foolproof way to
>   prevent the user from leaving this
>   View with an incorrect value in it,
>   all we can do is try to fix it
>   ourselves when this happens."

If your list of elements is not too long, you are probably better off using a Spinner.

******** Edit: ********

I wipped together a quick example of how you can use this, hope it helps!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<AutoCompleteTextView  
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Focus me to validate above text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

-

```
public class AutoCompleteTextViewActivity extends Activity {

    String[] validWords = new String[]{"", "snowboard", "bobsleigh", "slalom"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AutoCompleteTextView view = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.input);
        view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, validWords));
        view.setValidator(new Validator());
        view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusListener());
    }

    class Validator implements AutoCompleteTextView.Validator {

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(CharSequence text) {
            Log.v("Test", "Checking if valid: "+ text);
            Arrays.sort(validWords);
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(validWords, text.toString()) > 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence fixText(CharSequence invalidText) {
            Log.v("Test", "Returning fixed text");

            /* I'm just returning an empty string here, so the field will be blanked,
             * but you could put any kind of action here, like popping up a dialog?
             * 
             * Whatever value you return here must be in the list of valid words.
             */
            return "";
        }
    }

    class FocusListener implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.v("Test", "Focus changed");
            if (v.getId() == R.id.input && !hasFocus) {
                Log.v("Test", "Performing validation");
                ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).performValidation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Originally i used a Spinner, but my users were complaining so id thought id change it to a ACTV. Do you have any references to examples where the validator have been used? Im strugeling with the implementation.

Comment: I made a small example for you, just ask if something is still unclear!

Comment: Great example.. One obvious improvement would be to not sort the words though each time isValid is called.. Maybe maintain a sorted flag

Comment: there should be a donate button on SO

Comment: even though entered text is one from the array autocompplete textview turns blank after it looses its focus..when it again gets focus back it has last selected item as a pre filled text..weird thing happening :/

Comment: solved!!..somehow autocomplete is not setting text color as BLACK..did it manually now..thanks ..@rogerkk u r a champ!! keep rocking!

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer, but shouldn't this line of your code: 'if (Arrays.binarySearch(validWords, text.toString()) > 0)' be 'if (Arrays.binarySearch(validWords, text.toString()) > -1)' ? I think it will omit the first item in the sorted array if it is set to > 0 instead of > -1.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate way(comments are mentioned inline) :

```
AutoCompleteTextView txt_site_name  = findViewById(R.id.some_auto_text);
// Get the string array for the countries
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ncr_parking_list_array);
// Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, countries);
// txt_site_name  is name of the AutoComplete text view. or AutoCompleteTextView txt_site_name
txt_site_name.setAdapter(adapter);

txt_site_name.setValidator(new AutoCompleteTextView.Validator() {
     @Override
     public boolean isValid (CharSequence text){
          //some logic here returns true or false based on if the text is validated
          if(text == "This is what I want") 
              return true;
          else 
              return false;
     }

     @Override
     public CharSequence fixText (CharSequence invalidText){
          //If .isValid() returns false then the code comes here
          //do whatever way you want to fix in the users input and  return it
          return "This is what I want"
            }
        });
```

Reference: [AutoCompleteTextView.Validator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.Validator.html)