# How to force user to select a location from google place autocomplete items and not simply type it?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have a simple project of google place autocomplete. I want to force users to select from autocomplete items and place into the editText otherwise empty the editext.

I'm using the following code:

```
public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = "MY KEY";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

    autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:Ir");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            System.out.println("============================================================");
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return (String) resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
}
```

can somebody help me??

Thanks

Comment: use this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394054/android-restrict-user-to-select-from-autocompletion-textview-only,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033246/android-autocomplettextview-force-text-to-be-from-the-entry-list

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)